# How to use greek letters in \text environment inside math?

Tags: math-mode

I tried something like `$(\lambda x. x\ x)(\lambda x. x\ x) \text{cannot be \beta-reduced to something else}$`. How can I make TeX output a real beta where I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out how to do it by myself. I just had to encapsulate the `\beta` into dollar signs again: `$(\lambda x. x\ x)(\lambda x. x\ x) \text{cannot be $\beta$-reduced to something else}$`

Comment: While your answer is technically correct, I'd say it is basically wrong. The right answer is `$(\lambda x. x\ x)(\lambda x. x\ x)$ cannot be $\beta$-reduced …`. More generally, `\text` is very rarely appropriate in inline math. Display math is another story altogether.

Comment: In that regard, see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3415/215)

Comment: I'm using MathJAX, they only have math mode.

Comment: If you are using MathJax with HTML, why not just type the HTML entity? `&beta;-reduced` produces "β-reduced"

Comment: Hm... yes. That would be an option.