# Creating Macros for Math Text

Tags: math-mode, macros

The built-in commands for text in math mode, such as `\sup`, are formatted very nicely.  How can I define a macro for some short text that is to appear multiple times in math mode (such as "diam"), so that it mimics the formatting of something like `\sup`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With the `amsmath` package loaded:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\diam}{diam}
```

in your preamble. Use it in an equation with `\diam`. This will give you the upright text that you want, and the proper spacing. See section 5.1 of the [`amsmath` documentation](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) for more details. For single use, instead of defining a macro `\operatorname{diam}` will have the same effect if you use it directly inside an equation.

For bits of text that are not functions in the mathematical sense, e.g. if you want to put some upright text in a subscript, this package also makes the `\text{...}` command available. You can use this in a `\newcommand` as usual. See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3415/what-is-the-correct-way-of-embedding-text-into-math-mode) for a demonstration of the `\text` command.

Comment: You could also mention `\operatorname` for cases where an operator is only used once and defining a specific macro is not useful.

Comment: Indeed, although the question specifies multiple use. I will add this.