# Typing problem of word in $ $

Tags: math-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the “correct” way of embedding text into math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3415/what-is-the-correct-way-of-embedding-text-into-math-mode)

when I use `$$` for mathematics typing, sometimes like `$\left\{ x: x is an element of A\right\}$`, then it shows "isanelement" by a single word. How do I manage that?

Answer (score 3):

use `\text{ is an element of }`

Comment: Better yet, `\text{$x$ is an element of $A$}`, to guarantee consistent amounts of text whitespace between all words in the sentence.