# What formatting is perfect for word in an equation?

Tags: math-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the “correct” way of embedding text into math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3415/what-is-the-correct-way-of-embedding-text-into-math-mode)

What formatting is perfect for word in an equation?  Is `\text{ text is here }` the best way?  For example,

```
a = x_j \text{ for } i = 1, 2, \dots, M
```

Comment: Yes, and you could also use `\mbox{ text is here }`, but this will not scale to where it's used. Some also use `\ \text{text is here}\ `.

Comment: The whitespace before and after the text does look to close to the math.  Is `\ ` there to fix that?

Comment: Yes, the `\ ` is there to add additional space, but I think `$a = x_j \text{, for } i = ...` is better, but really up to you which to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Not sure whether this is an answer...</sub>

Spaces are gobbles and replaced with appropriate math spacing when in math mode. However, forced spacing always sets the same; there is no difference in the spacing between the following alternatives:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
$a = x_j \text{ for } i = 1, 2, \dots, M$ \par
$a = x_j\ \text{for } i = 1, 2, \dots, M$ \par
$a = x_j \text{ for}\ i = 1, 2, \dots, M$ \par
$a = x_j\ \text{for}\ i = 1, 2, \dots, M$ \par
$a = x_j \text{~for~} i = 1, 2, \dots, M$ \par
$a = x_j~\text{for~} i = 1, 2, \dots, M$ \par
$a = x_j \text{~for}~i = 1, 2, \dots, M$ \par
$a = x_j~\text{for}~i = 1, 2, \dots, M$
\end{document}
```

As such, it may be left up to user preference. That is, whether you consider the space before/after the text to form part of the text or not and what kind of spacing you use.