# no space between words in equation

Tags: equations

I wrote a simple equation like this

```
\begin{equation}
  Compress Ratio = \frac{n-u} {n} \times 100
\end{equation}
```

However in the output there is no "space" between `Compress` and `Ratio` and they are concatenated.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Load `amsmath` and use `\text{Compress Ratio}`

Comment: Yes that works however the the final text in the pdf is not bold. Symbols such as `u` and `n` are bold. `100` and `Compress Ratio` are not bold. Is that normal?

Comment: Or just type `\mbox{Compress Ratio}` without the `amsmath` package

Comment: Without an MWE we don't have a clue why they are bold. Please provide an MWE.

Comment: Is this [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3415/31058) useful in your case?

Comment: What about just using `\textbf{Compress Ratio}`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 \text{Compress Ratio}=\frac{n-u} {n} \times 100
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I would rather do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 C=\frac{n-u} {n} \times 100
\end{equation}
where $C$ denotes the compress ratio.
\end{document}
```

Always remember to typeset all math inside math environments `$x$` etc., and put the least possible text inside.

Answer (score 3):

`\mbox{Compress Ratio}` when you are inside math.