# How do you display words, not variables, in equations in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, statistics

In particular, I need to display the following:
P(success) = size of successful region/size of possible region
But with a nice divisor line for the fraction. If I just enter this in typical fashion LaTeX makes each letter look like a variable:

```
$P(success) = \frac{size of successful region}{size of possible region}$
```

Comment: You add [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) to your preamble (`\usepackage{amsmath}`) and use `\text{...}` in your equation. See [What is the “correct” way of embedding text into math mode?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3415/5764)

Comment: @Werner However, I would probably prefer `\mathrm{...}` over `\text{...}` here.

Comment: @tohecz what's the difference between `\mathrm` and `\text`?

Comment: @Werner `\text` worked perfect! Create an answer so I can credit you. @tohecz the `\mathrm` gave me my text but without spaces.

Comment: @at. -- `\text` may work here, but if this display is set within an italicized theorem, `\text` will follow the style of the surrounding text, and be (text) italic, which is probably not what you want, hence the suggestion for `\mathrm`.  alternatively, `\text{\upshape ...}` should also ensure a roman style.