# Using display mode and adding space between text

Tags: displaystyle

I have this...

```
\[c1*f(n) \leq f(n) \leq c2* f(n)\ \forall n_0 \geq 0\]
```

For display mode, I want to add additional space before \forall.  I'm not too familiar with display mode.  I tried just adding space and it doesn't seem do anything.

Comment: Related: [What is the "correct" way of embedding text into math mode?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3415) Do you really want to write "... less than or equal to c2*f(n) for for all n_0 ..." though? Isn't one "for" enough?

Comment: How about `\mbox{ for }`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. that's how it was written on the board but yeah it doesn't make sense.  How do I add proper spacing then between the two statements?  I want both to be on the same line but have some distance between the two

Comment: I'm going to update the question

Comment: I ended up using \begin{center} and \mbox to get around this.

Comment: LaTeX User guide, p.52 `\,` thin space; `\:` medium space; `\!` negative thin space; and `\;` thick space.  In addition, one can always use `\mkern<number>mu` or `\kern<length>`.  Also, there is `\quad` and `\qquad` for larger spaces.

Comment: Why the `center` environment? Displayed math is centered by default (in standard classes at least), unless you add `fleqn` as an option to the documentclass or `amsmath`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.  I was just brute forcing a solution.  Thanks for proper hanlding and for the tip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See an example below. Was the `*` intended as a multiplication symbol here? In that case I would write `\cdot` instead, and perhaps you want 1 and 2 as subscripts to the c's? If that is the case, then

```
\[
c_1\cdot f(n) \leq f(n) \leq c_2 \cdot f(n) \quad \forall n_0 \geq 0
\]
```

Output of the code below:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Removing ``for'' altogether. (For a bigger space, use \verb|\qquad|.)
\[
c1* f(n) \leq f(n) \leq c2 * f(n) \quad \forall n_0 \geq 0
\]
But if you want to include it:
\[
c1* f(n) \leq f(n) \leq c2 * f(n) \text{ for } \forall n_0 \geq 0
\]
Or for a little bit more space.
\[
c1* f(n) \leq f(n) \leq c2 * f(n) \quad \text{for} \quad\forall n_0 \geq 0
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I definitely prefer this way over my hack :)