# Math equations non italic

Tags: equations

I am using \begin{equation} to write equation but it is in italic. How do i disable it ? The other threads all not for \begin{equation}. everything inside it is green

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq:oa}
Overlap Area = \frac{Area (Detection \cap Ground Truth)}{Area (Detection \cup Ground Truth )}
\end{equation}
```

My main code below

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=3.5cm, right=3cm]{geometry}

% graphics images
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{slashbox}

% 1.5 line spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\onehalfspacing

% maths symbols
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[math-style = upright]{unicode-math}

% table package
\usepackage{multirow}

% citation style
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}%
\makeatletter
\let\Hy@linktoc\Hy@linktoc@none
\makeatother

\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

%\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}

\usepackage{tikz,colortbl}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}

\usepackage[bf,small,tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

% cover
\input{cover_report.tex}

% title page
%\input{title_report.tex}

% abstract
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\input{abstract.tex}

% acknowledgement
\input{acknowledgements.tex}

% table of content
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}

% list of tables
%\listoftables
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}

% list of figures
%\listoffigures
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}

% intro chapter
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{intro.tex}
\input{literature.tex}
%\input{propose.tex}
\input{module_design.tex}
\input{training.tex}
\input{results.tex}
\input{conclusion.tex}
% references
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{fyp}

% appendix
%\input{appendix.tex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you show a whole compilable code? Usually, the standard for mathematical writing is that variables are set in italic.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Of course in the math environments the variables are in italic, but operators are in upright shape. Both use fonts for math (usually are part of used fonts or is the same) ... If you not like to write equations as other do, you need to change math fonts.

Comment: You can use the `unicode` package with the option `\usepackage[math-style = upright]{unicode-math}` (compile with `xelatex`)

Comment: If you are trying to write words inside a math environment, you could use `\text{you text}` from `amsmath`-package.

Comment: Hi sorry. I have edited my post to include my equation

Comment: Unrelated note: You usually don't want to specify the driver (`pdftex`) for the `graphicx` package, so remove the `pdftex` argument there, and also from the documentclass settings. `graphicx` detects which driver to use.  (And if you're using `unicode-math`, then you're *not* using `pdftex` anyway, so it's even the wrong driver I guess.)

Comment: @RunarTrollet, do you mind to convert your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside a math environment, LaTeX assumes that every letter is a variable, and will typeset it in a math font with italics, and ignore all spaces.

To tell LaTeX that you are typing in text, you could use the `text{}` command from the `amsmath`-package. Here I load the `mathtools`-package, which in turn loads `amsmath`.

You could also use `\textrm{}` without loading any packages, but I recommend using `\text{}`. Have a look at [What is the "correct" way of embedding text into math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3415/what-is-the-correct-way-of-embedding-text-into-math-mode)

Here, you mix text with math symbols, like the `\cap`. These symbols need to be typeset in math mode. You can do this by surrounding the symbol with `\(` and `\)` , like this: `\( \cap \)`. You might have seen a TeX-equivalent of this, where `$`-signs were used, but this is against recommendations and the old way of doing it. For more information about this, see:  [Are `\(` and `\)` preferable to `$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/510)

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:oa}
\text{Overlap Area} = \frac{ \text{Area (Detection \(\cap\) Ground Truth)} }{ \text{Area (Detection \(\cup\) Ground Truth)} }
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: or `\frac{\text{Area (Detection}\cap\text{ Ground Truth)}}{\text{Area (Detection}\cup\text{Ground Truth)}}` ?

Comment: @Zarko I think the spacing would be wrong, even if you were consistent with the space introduced before `Ground`, and either removed it in both or added it in both.

Comment: @Zarko `\Area(\text{Detection} \cap \text{Ground Truth})` with `\DeclareMathOperator\Area{Area}`. Altough I've been lately thinking that `\text` is not the right tool for this job. I would use `\mathrm` or `\textnormal` when needed (or better, a symbolic and semantic macro that would ease the change of the ouput just changing the definition).

Comment: @Manuel It could be interesting to see your take on this in the question I linked to in my post. Consider making an answer there. Again, link to post: [What is the “correct” way of embedding text into math mode?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3415/what-is-the-correct-way-of-embedding-text-into-math-mode)

Comment: Thanks for the answer runar ! Managed to get it to work after following your post and some other suggestions from the others. I'm very new to latex. I downloaded this template from http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/aseschng/teaching/teaching.html for my project so all the commands and syntax feels new