# Spacing around a comma to separates conditions (in math mode)

Tags: math-mode, punctuation

Let say I have a set

```
\{ x \in A : first condition , second condition , third condition \},
```

or as a more explicit example

```
\{ x \in A : x > 0 , x^2 \in B , x^3 \notin C \}.
```

I find that the spacing around the commas are too small, and sometime it makes it hard to identify the different conditions. What would be a good practice to have nice spacing there?

I thought of `\ , \`. But I really does not like it, since the code is messy afterwards. An other solution I thought of is `\mathbin{,}` or `\mathrel{,}`.
Does anyone has better suggestion or motivations for choosing one of these solutions over the others.

Comment: The punctuation should really be in text mode not math mode, try `\text{ , }` (note the spaces around the comma). Spaces are usually ignored in math mode.

Comment: @ArTourter I don't agree with half of your command, because there should not be a space before the comma, see for Example [this answer on English.SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/4646/143165). Different rules might apply in other languages.

Comment: If you feel a space is needed `,\ ` is usually enough. I agree with dadeix86 space in in front of `,` looks bad

Comment: @ArTourter At the moment, I find your comment the most satisfying answer. If you turn at as an answer I will accept (except if something new comes in, in the meanwhile).

Answer (score 5):

Related to [something I wrote recently](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3415/what-is-the-correct-way-of-embedding-text-into-math-mode/318124#318124), I would use `,\`  in math mode, and just “text mode” when text is involved. I put `“”` because by text mode I don't mean `\text`.

```
\newcommand*\mathwords{\textnormal}
$\{ x \in A : \mathwords{first condition, second condition, third condition} \}$
$\{ x \in A : x > 0 ,\ x^2 \in B ,\ x^3 \notin C \}$
```

[image]

Something should be done so that TeX would break between lines and hyphenate the words in `\mathwords`, ideally. But here it's just an example.

Answer (score 2):

You could do exactly what you described using `\ , \` , but with a new command in order to make things clearer:

```
\newcommand{\setsep}{ \ , \ }

\begin{document}
\{ x \in A : x > 0 \setsep x^2 \in B \setsep x^3 \notin C \}.
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

You can also use `\textbf{}` to make the comma even more apparent:

```
\newcommand{\setsep}{ \ \textbf{,} \ }

\begin{document}
\{ x \in A : x > 0 \setsep x^2 \in B \setsep x^3 \notin C \}.
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]