# How to write capital alpha?

Tags: fonts, greek

Unfortunately, the command `\Alpha` does not produce capital version of `\alpha` (as one might expect in analogy with how, say, `\Pi` produces capital `\pi`). It so happens that the capital alpha looks rather similar to `A`, but that doesn't mean that there aren't situations where I would like to use capital alpha in a formula. For instance, suppose I already have `\pi` which belongs to a set `\Pi`, and then `\alpha` comes along and I need a name for the set of its possible values.

What is the best way to write capital alpha?

The obvious first attempt is to just write `A`. But it's not right - `A` produces italic `A`, while Greek letters are by default not italic. Would `\mathrm{A}` do the trick, or is there some subtle issue I'm not noticing? Is there a package that will save me the work of defining all capital letters by hand?

Comment: Yes, it is `\mathrm{A}`.

Comment: Slight correction: uppercase Greek letters are by default not italic in math, but lowercase ones are.

Comment: How will your readers distinguish between Alpha and A?

Comment: @egreg - With any luck, Alpha and A will not appear anywhere close to one another. And even if they do, one will be italic and the other one won't.

Answer (score 36):

If you're using LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you can use the `unicode-math` package. It defines all uppercase Greek letters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$\Alpha+\Beta=\Gamma$.
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

This way has an advantage in that one can change the style of the letters by altering the `unicode-math` options. For example `\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}` without any other changes yields:

[image]

Also, this way alpha can be copied&pasted from the resulting PDF.

Comment: -1 for dependence on IDE/engine.

Comment: @RosieF There’s no dependence on IDE. Posting a solution that uses newer technology does not merit a downvote unless it fails to answer the question, i.e. ignoring the specified requirements. This site should encourage posting alternative solutions, some of which use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Comment: @RosieF It is impossible to *use* TeX without using some specific TeX engine. If commonly used implementations behave differently (which may be unfortunate, but is a fact of life) understanding the differences is an important part of the answer.

Comment: +1: @RosieF I also no not see any reason for a downvote at all.

Comment: @RosieF By the same logic, all questions that depend on LaTeX instead of just base TeX should be downvoted, since that is an extremely large dependence!

Comment: +1 Because it's a good solution. Also, @RosieF, there is no reason to downvote (see comments above).

Comment: I think @RosieF is simply unaware of the upvoting culture on our TeX site. Isn't there a Meta question or smth we could guide her to?

Comment: When I apply your solution it just outputs `+ = Γ.` where I cannot see A and B is it normal?

Comment: @alper how exactly did you compile the document? Can you show the log file?

Comment: The way I compile is: `pdflatex --shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode my_file.tex`: output of log: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/bcf6d9ad435627c96b354ac18378649d

Comment: Well, the solution is specifically for LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX. You can't do that with pdfLaTeX.

Comment: @alper Also, when you are using nonstopmode, you basically ignores any error in your document. You should never ignore errors.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan I didn't realize question was for LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX. Thanks for the heads up, I will not ignore errors in my document :-)

Answer (score 20):

Screenshot from [`lshort.pdf`](http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf) (The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e):

[image]

So it is simply `\mathrm{A}`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\newcommand\Alpha{\mathrm{A}}
\begin{document}
$\Alpha+\Pi=\Gamma$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for independence from IDE/engine.

Comment: This cannot print `\Eta`  is it normal?

Comment: \Eta is the same as H.

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend `unicode-math` and Sergei Golovan’s solution if you are able to use it.  Fewer and fewer publishers force you to use PDFTeX.

Here is a PDFTeX-compatible solution that produces a Greek Α and Β instead of a Latin A and B:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lmodern, amsmath}

\newcommand\mupAlpha{\mathord{\text{%
\fontencoding{LGR}\upshape\selectfont \textAlpha}}}
\newcommand\mupBeta{\mathord{\text{%
\fontencoding{LGR}\upshape\selectfont \textBeta}}}

\begin{document}
\( \mupAlpha + \mupBeta = \Gamma \)
\end{document}
```

[image: Latin Modern Font Sample]

I chose the names `\mupAlpha` and `\mupBeta`, which are compatible with `unicode-math`, because they always produce a regular-weight, upright letter.  It would also be possible to define italic `\mitAlpha` and bold `\mbfAlpha` by inserting `\itshape` or `\bfseries`.  Or you could call it `\Alpha`.

Another alternative is to declare LGR-encoded symbol alphabets and `\DeclareMathSymbol`, but be careful you don’t run out of math alphabets, which are a limited resource in the legacy toolchain.  There are a number of packages that define Greek math-mode fonts, including `upgreek`.  Both `mathastext` and `isomath` have options to load a LGR font for your Greek letters in math mode.

In theory, you could try the `alphabeta` package to use commands such as `\Alpha` in either text or math mode, and also insert the Unicode characters in math mode.  However, it produces inconsistent results: *Α* + *Β* = Γ.  In practice, if you want to mix different scripts, you’re much better off with Unicode and the modern toolchain designed for that.

Comment: Did you try `$x_{\mupAlpha}$`?

Comment: @egreg Oof! Thanks for [the reminder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3415/what-is-the-correct-way-of-embedding-text-into-math-mode).

Comment: Looking back at this answer, it might or might not have a bug. `\mathAlpha`, etc., don’t reset the font series, so a `\bfseries` command will bleed over. This might actually be desirable, if it appears in a chapter or section title!  To fix it, replace `\text` with `\textnormal` or call `\usefont` within `\text` to set all font porperties at once.

Answer (score 7):

This works with the default Computer Modern fonts. A different font family should be chosen if the font is different (and it should have support for the LGR encoding).

I redefined also `\Delta` because the correspondence when copying maps the standard `\Delta` to U+2206 INCREMENT.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc} % or OT1

\DeclareSymbolFont{upgreek}{LGR}{cmr}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{upgreek}{bold}{LGR}{cmr}{bx}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\Alpha}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Beta}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Delta}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Epsilon}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Zeta}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`Z}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Eta}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`H}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Iota}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`I}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Kappa}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`K}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Mu}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`M}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Nu}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`N}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Omicron}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`O}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Rho}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`R}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Tau}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`T}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Chi}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`Q}


\begin{document}

$\Alpha\Beta\Gamma\Delta\Epsilon\Zeta\Eta\Theta\Iota\Kappa\Lambda\Mu$

$\Nu\Xi\Omicron\Pi\Rho\Sigma\Tau\Upsilon\Phi\Chi\Psi\Omega$

{\mathversion{bold}$\Alpha\Beta\Gamma\Delta$}

\end{document}
```

You could also avoid the dependency from `LGR`, but in this case you have to set up a font family in the U encoding.

[image]

Below what I get by copy-paste:

```
ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜ ΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ ΑΒΓΔ
```

If you define `\Alpha` as `\mathrm{A}` you just get the same glyph, but upon copying it would be A.