# calendar.sty not compatible with LuaTeX - bold fonts are no longer bold

Tags: luatex, bold, bugs, calendar

I am a long-time user of [`calendar.sty`](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/monthly-calendar-latex-template/cptqrrzlprns), however I am new to LuaTeX / LuaLaTeX.

I switched to LuaLaTeX so I could use Greek letters from the LuaLaTeX package `unicode-math` package (see [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/233288/48036) and [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/485598/48036)). The transition to LuaTeX was mostly smooth, except I noticed that **bold** fonts are no longer working.

The culprit seems to be the `calendar.sty` package. When using `calendar.sty`, bold fonts render correctly with PDFTeX but not with LuaTeX. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[inner=1.5cm,outer=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

%from https://www.latextemplates.com/template/monthly-calendar
\usepackage{calendar} % Use the calendar.sty style
\usepackage{palatino} % Use the Palatino font

\title{Test}
\author{Ethan Alvarée}
\date{July 2022}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
Hello. I am testing \textbf{bold} fonts.
\end{document}
```

Here is a [live Overleaf project](https://www.overleaf.com/read/tdshzpfxgprd) demonstrating the issue. Any workaround ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: remove the palatino package, that is not meant for lualatex. Use e.g. `\setmainfont{texgyrepagella}` instead (that is a palatino clone).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not calendar but palatino. If you look into the log-file you will see two warnings:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/ppl/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 79.
```

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/ppl/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/ppl/m/n' instead on input line 81.
```

which together mean that the font family `ppl` setup by the package is not supported by lualatex and so you actually get the default Latin Modern font.

Use `\setmainfont` to setup your fonts, e.g. you can use the palatino clone from the tex gyre fonts with `\setmainfont{texgyrepagella}`.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you Ulrike!