# \Tau causes an error

Tags: pdftex, unicode, greek

I use https://oeis.org/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_mathematical_symbols for symbols. It normally works. but when i want to use \Tau (or any greek symbols whose code starts with a capital for that matter) I get the error "Undefined control sequence.
l.142 ... \in \mathbb{N}} $ dizisini  $ x_n = \Tau " how do I fix this?

Comment: Your link references a non-TeX system that makes `\Tau` available. Since a greek Tau would look like a latin `T` there's no command for it. Just use a `T`.

Comment: "or any greek symbols whose code starts with a capital" doubt that, try `\Gamma`, or `\Pi`. As @Qrrbrbirlbel states the reason `\Tau` doesn't work is because it looks just like `T` and so to save space (which was a concern back in the days more than now) the Greek letters which just look like Latin ones weren't defined.

Comment: Somewhat related question, [symbols - omicron not working in LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233257/omicron-not-working-in-latex) // [fonts - How to write capital alpha? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485593/how-to-write-capital-alpha)

Answer (score 4):

The command `\Tau` is defined when `unicode-math` is used, because it must refer to the Greek letter.

In legacy TeX there is no such command, because a Tau has the same shape as a T. The same for

```
\Alpha \Beta \Epsilon \Zeta \Eta \Iota \Kappa \Mu \Nu \Omicron \Rho \Chi
```

because the corresponding glyphs have the same shape as a Latin Letter.

You might want to say

```
\providecommand{\Tau}{\mathrm{T}}
\providecommand{\varTau}{T}
```

to get, respectively, the upright Tau (actually a T) and the slanted one, like for `\varGamma` and `\varPi`.

Add also the commands for the other letters, if you want.