# Mingled math and text in math mode

Tags: math-mode, best-practices

I frequently encounter the situation of wanting to, say, write a set where the set-membership condition involves some text.  If I wanted to describe, say, the set of all even integers this way, then would it be better to write

```
\{x \in \mathbb Z : \text{$x$ is even}\}
```

or

```
\{x \in \mathbb Z : x\text{ is even}\}
```

?  Of course there are obvious quibbles (maybe you like `\mathbb{Z}` rather than `\mathbb Z`; maybe you like some other delimiter than `:`, or some manual space around it), but I'm asking *only* which way is preferable for writing intermingled text and math in math mode—and, if possible, a reason why other than personal preference.

(I was convinced long ago to use the former by someone who argued that it's semantically more sensible, but I don't know if it's the best practice, or, if it is, whether there's any TeXnical reason for it.)

Comment: I vote for the second one, see if this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3415/what-is-the-correct-way-of-embedding-text-into-math-mode may help you.

Comment: [@CarLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522278/mingled-math-and-text-in-math-mode#comment1320873_522278), thanks!  [That](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3415/what-is-the-correct-way-of-embedding-text-into-math-mode) seems to be more about mbox vs. mathrm than the issue raised here; but this issue did come up, and anon [voted for the first](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3917).

Comment: I'm not an expert, I can't give you a TeX reason for my preference, let's see if some TeXnician replies :)

Comment: I would prefer the first way. Only reason: it’s more readable.

Comment: [@Fractal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522278/mingled-math-and-text-in-math-mode#comment1320882_522278), more readable as source or as compiled document, or both?

Comment: `\{` ...`\}` ? ... I would use simply  `\(x \in \mathbb Z : x\) is even`

Comment: @LSpice Please only @ me without the link, otherwise I am not notified. Answer: the source is more readable. The document? It doesn't change at all.

Comment: @Fran Using `\{` `\}` is the standard notation in some countries including mine.

Comment: @Fractal One more reason to add a MWE.

Answer (score 2):

```
\{x \in \mathbb Z : \text{$x$ is even}\}
```

is semantically correct and preferable.

The output of both options will be identical in terms of spacing, but semantically, the *x* in “*x* is even” belongs to the phrase which is text mode and not to the surrounding context.

Answer (score 0):

*Note* Do not use this method for your actual work or in your professional capacity. It is a mere *jeu d'esprit*. This is not recommended for *actual* maths, which is 99% layout (such as glyph shapes, spacings and proportions and so on, to convey meaning in a standardized way), but is meant *only* to illustrate that all unicode glyphs are just that, glyphs, and so are "text-able" (as far as that can take anyone). There is a (natural) tendency to consider the (996) mathematical alphanumeric symbols as just a text glyph with formatting applied (e.g. bold, italic), or originating from a different font file/style altogether (e.g., sans, fraktur, script), but, in Unicode, all these  are completely different glyphs (in the *same* font), not just the same text x codepoint in fancy dress (from potentially a mixture of different fonts).

---

Just to celebrate end-of-year, without delimiters ...

If I type directly in unicode:

```
 ∈ ℤ :  is even
```

(and the font has text Latin in it as well, like XITS Math does), then I get:

[image: everything is text]

MWE

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{XITS Math}
%\usepackage{unicode-math}
%\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\begin{document}
%\[x \in \mathbb Z : \text{$x$ is even}\]

 ∈ ℤ :  is even

\end{document}
```

... so the question is moot, perhaps.  :)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't recommend this way. The , ∈ and ℤ are treated as in text mode, so unexpected things may happen. Moreover, the spacing is not the "standard" consistent math spacing, but only a normal text-mode space.

Comment: I agree with @Fractal, this is not the way to go, sorry but -1

Comment: @CarLaTeX I don't think a downvote is necessary. From his wording, it is quite clear that this answer is not meant to be serious. It is kind of "just for fun".

Comment: @Fractal I like fun posts but not if they give wrong information.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Ah, I remember that sad episode.

Comment: I'll add a rider, to make it clearer.

Comment: I've left my downvote due to your edit, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I’d say the best practice is to write

```
x \textnormal{ is even}
```

As for `x \textnormal{...}` versus `\textnormal{$x$ ...}`, the former is simpler and the latter can easily lead to mismatched `$` signs.  You could at least alleviate that with `\textnormal{\(x\) is even}`, but that takes even more characters.

Unlike `\text`, this resets all formatting.  If you’ve changed the formatting of the surrounding text—such as an italicized theorem statement, or a bold header, that would bleed through into math mode if you use `\text`.   (Which might be what you want in some cases.)