# Straight letters in TeX?

Tags: letters

How do I get straight letters while assigning variables? For a variable P, I currently use `\text{P}` to straighten it but syntactically speaking, it doesn't seem like the right way to do this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Do you mean this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3415/what-is-the-correct-way-of-embedding-text-into-math-mode?

Comment: If you're not stuck to Computer (or Latin) Modern, the `fourier` package, based on Adobe Utopia,  has an `upright` option which uses the French style: uppercase letters are upright, as well as lowercase and uppercase greek letters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe `\mathrm` may be what you're looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[ \mathrm{ ABC} \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, don't use `minimal` for examples: it's not meant for that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Why isn't it?

Comment: See [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114)

Comment: @egreg why hasn't that class never been renamed? If it is only for testing, how many people in the wild rely on it?

Comment: @daleif Who knows? It has *never* been advertised as a class for minimal typesetting examples, though.

Comment: @egreg thanks. Amusingly enough, it was only through examples here on TeX.SE that I learned that `minimal` existed at all!

Comment: @chsk That's why there's an entry in the “often referenced questions” about it.

Comment: @egreg Where are those found?

Comment: @chsk https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/often-referenced-questions

Comment: Excellent. Thanks, @Phelype!